# Returning timer job status from custom timer job

Tags: sharepoint, timer-jobs

There is a timer job status page in Central Admin
/_admin/ServiceRunningJobs.aspx

How can I properly return the status for my custom timer job ?

The `Execute()` method of timer job returns `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It either fails (Exception) or succeeds (Method completes)

Answer (score 1):

`SPJobDefinition.UpdateProgress`